# ¿Cómo puedo leer un archivo txt extrayendo la información que está separada por comas?

Tags: java, csv, procesamiento-de-texto

```
package leerArchivo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LectorFactura {
    
    public ArrayList <Factura> lista = new ArrayList <Factura>();
    
    public LectorFactura(String RegistroConsumo) {
        cargarLista(RegistroConsumo);
    }
    private void cargarLista(String RegistroConsumo) {
        try {
            ArrayList<String>listaRegistro;
            listaRegistro = new ArrayList <> (Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(RegistroConsumo)));
            cargarFactura(listaRegistro);
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    private void cargarFactura(ArrayList<String>listaRegistro) {
        for (String s:listaRegistro) {
            int ind = s.indexOf(",");
            String tipoConsumidor = s.substring(0,ind);
            String nombreCliente = s.substring(0,ind+1);
            String direccion = s.substring(ind+1);
            int ultimo = s.length();
            s = s.substring(ind+1,ultimo);
            ind = s.indexOf(",");
            int identificadorCliente = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(ind+1));
            double consumo = Double.parseDouble(s.substring(ind+1));
            
        }
    }
}
```

Necesito leer la información dentro de un archivo txt y extraerla, la misma está separada por comas. Intenté hacerlo con el método, debo diferenciarlas de la siguiente forma:

1. Lo que está antes de la primer coma guardarlo en tipoConsumidor
2. Lo que está luego de la primer coma guardarlo en nombreCliente
3. Lo que está luego de la segunda coma guardarlo en direccion
4. Lo que está luego de la tercer coma guardarlo en identificadorCliente
5. Lo que está luego de la cuarta coma guardarlo en consumo

Fragmento del texto:

1. F,Ana Perez,Yi 1122,23232111,8
2. F,Jose Diaz,Oribe 123,1231234,18
3. C,La Pizzeria,Rivera 3322,21001122331,21
4. C,El Lavadero,Colonia 2312,2100321321,54
5. C,El fogon,Soriano 1515,2134211231,36
6. F,Roberto Rivas,19 de abril 2020,121212122,45

Ignoren la enumeración, es simplemente para que se noten los enter y no aparezca la información como una tira entera sin separadores

Clase factura:

```
package leerArchivo;

public class Factura {
    
    private String tipoConsumidor;
    private String nombreCliente;
    private String direccion;
    private int identificadorCliente;
    private double consumo;
    
    public Factura (String tipoConsumidor, String nombreCliente, String direccion, int identificadorCliente, double consumo) {
        super ();
        this.tipoConsumidor=tipoConsumidor;
        this.nombreCliente=nombreCliente;
        this.direccion=direccion;
        this.identificadorCliente=identificadorCliente;
        this.consumo=consumo;
        
    
    }

    public String getTipoConsumidor() {
        return tipoConsumidor;
    }

    public void setTipoConsumidor(String tipoConsumidor) {
        this.tipoConsumidor = tipoConsumidor;
    }

    public String getNombreCliente() {
        return nombreCliente;
    }

    public void setNombreCliente(String nombreCliente) {
        this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public int getIdentificadorCliente() {
        return identificadorCliente;
    }

    public void setIdentificadorCliente(int identificadorCliente) {
        this.identificadorCliente = identificadorCliente;
    }

    public double getConsumo() {
        return consumo;
    }

    public void setConsumo(double consumo) {
        this.consumo = consumo;
    }

    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Factura [tipoConsumidor=" + tipoConsumidor + ", nombreCliente=" + nombreCliente + ", direccion="
                + direccion + ", identificadorCliente=" + identificadorCliente + ", consumo=" + consumo + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez ahí realicé los cambios que me recomendaste, te agradecería mucho si pudieras ayudarme. Lamento que te parezca un tema que "derrite los ojos" pero soy estudiante y hay cosas que aún no logro comprender.

Comment: Me refería al tema claro de tu IDE que se mostraba en las fotos, no al tema de la pregunta como tal. Gracias por mejorar tu publicación. Deja ver si puedo echarte una mano.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez te pido disculpas por la malinterpretarte en ese caso, desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Puedes adjuntar tu clase factura? Es que no sé como has definido el constructor, por tanto, no sé como creas una factura para agregarla a la lista de facturas. Así quedaría tu método https://pastebin.com/RneeuhcY, solo que no lo puedo continuar sin la facturas.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez ahí quedó agregada la clase factura

Comment: Considera lo siguiente. El número máximo que puedes guardar en una variable `int` es `2 147 483 647` pero tienes un idCliente con valor `21 001 122 331`. Eso va a lanzarte un error cuando lo intentes parsear. O bien, cambia ese `idCliente` a algo más pequeño o considera cambiar el tipo de la variable a `long`.

Answer (score 0):

No utilices `indexOf` en combinación con `substring` para localizar las comas en tus líneas. En cambio, usa el método `split`.

El método `split` toma una cadena y la corta por el carácter que le pases como parámetro, devolviéndote un arreglo de los fragmentos. Por ejemplo:

```
"F,Ana Perez,Yi 1122,23232111,8".split(",")
```

Devolverá el arreglo:

```
["F", "Ana Perez", "Yi 1122", "23232111", "8"]
```

Por tanto, en la posición 0 del arreglo siempre estará el tipo de consumidor, en la posición 1 siempre estará el nombre, en la posición 2 siempre estará la dirección... y así sucesivamente. Como ves, es una forma mucho más fácil de parsear la cadena.

Teniendo en cuenta esto, tu método `cargarFactura` quedaría:

```
private void cargarFactura(ArrayList<String>listaRegistro) {
        for (String s:listaRegistro) {
            String[] datos = s.split( "," );
            String tipoConsumidor = datos[0];
            String nombreCliente = datos[1];
            String direccion = datos[2];
            int identificadorCliente = Integer.parseInt(datos[3]);
            double consumo = Double.parseDouble(datos[4]);

            // crear aca la factura y agregarla al ArrayList <Factura>
            Factura factura = new Factura( tipoConsumidor, nombreCliente, direccion,identificadorCliente,consumo );
            this.lista.add( factura );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias